# Best practice to store shared data between pages and how to control it

Tags: java, session, oracle-adf

I am building Fusion web application using `ADF` Technology in `Jdeveloper 11.1.2.3`. Some time we need to store shared variables among pages like ***employee id, employee role and some time `Boolean` variables used as flag attributes***.

My Question is what is the best practice to do that? Now I am using the `session scope` to store these data but I am not sure if it is the preferred way or not.

For example if I want to store some thing in the session I am doing the following:

```
        FacesContext fc = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();
        ExternalContext ectx = fc.getExternalContext();
        HttpSession userSession = (HttpSession)ectx.getSession(true);
        userSession.setAttribute("userID", [user id attribute goes here]);
```

If I want to get it back I am doing the following:

```
        Map sessionScope = ADFContext.getCurrent().getSessionScope();
        [data type] userIDFromSession = ([data type])sessionScope.get("userID");
```

But I do not know how to clear the session during execution and I do not know if there is better way to do the same thing.

Answer (score 0):

If these are values from the page, why are you accessing them from the backing Java code? Why not use Expression Language?
If the pages are in the same Task Flow then you should use PageFlowScope. Create a bean, MyBean, and access like this in the Expression Language:
 #{pageFlowScope.myBean.attribute}
When page is submitted, getAttribute is called automatically. When page is rendered, setAttribute is called automatically.
To acccess beans from the backing Java code, there are useful methods in this utility class, [here](https://sites.google.com/site/joeztechland/adf-information-sources/how-to--in-adf/adf-utility-classes).